# Instantiation of inner class of another class

Tags: java, android, static, inner-classes, non-static

I have the following setup which I would think would work but is giving an error in my IDE (Android Studio):

```
// MyClass1.java
public class MyClass1{
    public MyClass1(){}
    public class MyNestedClass1{}
}

// MyClass2.java
public class MyClass2{
    public static MyClass1 MY_CLASS1 = new MyClass1();
    public MyClass2(){
        new MY_CLASS1.MyNestedClass1(); //Error
    }
}
```

The specific IDE error is:

> cannot resolve symbol MyNestedClass1

Comment: Saying _non-static inner_ is redundant. _inner_ means _non-static_ nested class.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I changed the title.

Comment: There is no static class here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is

```
MY_CLASS1.new MyNestedClass1(); //No Error
```

Syntax is

```
<Expression that resolves to a reference of the enclosing class>.new [Name of nested inner class](..)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm sure this is already covered but I did not really find anything or know what term to search for in this situation. Appreciate it!

Comment: And as the ugliness of the syntax indicates, this is not something you should be doing. These inner classes should be managed by their containing class.

Comment: @Thilo what do you mean by managed? Should I not expose the class directly, and instead instantiate it in the parent class only?

Comment: Design advice without seeing the bigger picture is impossible, but as a guideline, no one except the owning instance should create inner class instances.

Answer (score 1):

```
// MyClass2.java
public class MyClass2{
    public static MyClass1 MY_CLASS1 = new MyClass1();//you have already instantiated MyClass1 by new operator here
    public MyClass2(){
        MY_CLASS1.new MyNestedClass1(); //so now intantiate only inner class by new operator
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define the nested class as `static`. This would allow instantiation independently of a **MyClass1**.

```
// MyClass1.java
public class MyClass1{
    public MyClass1(){}
    public static class MyNestedClass1{}
}

// MyClass2.java
public class MyClass2{
    public MyClass2(){
        /* One Way. */
        new MyClass1.MyNestedClass1();
        /* Or Another. */
        new MyNestedClass1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually need non-static because I use a member from the outerclass. Sorry, I just left that out of the example to simplify the situation. Still good to know, +1.